# Wrong output for given input

Tags: python, class, math

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/python
#gets the id of the player
player = input()


first_moves = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]
second_moves = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]

class calculate_bid(object):
    def __init__(self,player,first_moves,second_moves):
        self.myMove=[]
        self.yourMove=[]
        self.myCash=100
        self.yourCash=100
        self.pos=0
        if player==1:
            self.myMove.extend(first_moves)
            self.yourMove.extend(second_moves)
            self.tie=True
        else:
            self.myMove.extend(second_moves)
            self.yourMove.extend(first_moves)
            self.tie=False
        for self.x in range(len(self.myMove)):
            if self.myMove[self.x]>self.yourMove[self.x]:
                self.myCash-=self.myMove[self.x]
                self.pos+=1
            elif self.myMove<self.yourMove[self.x]:
                self.yourCash-=self.yourMove[self.x]
                self.pos+=1
            else:
                if self.tie==True:
                    self.myCash-=self.myMove[self.x]
                    self.pos+=1
                    self.tie=False
                else:
                    self.yourCash-=self.yourMove[self.x]
                    self.pos-=1
                    self.tie=True
        print self.myCash,self.yourCash
```

Why, if I give this input

```
2
4 15
8 8
```

does it print

```
92,-15
```

?

Note:
I don't think this only happens on my computer only. The same occurs when I run this one in HackerRank.

Note:
`yourCash` becomes zero WHEN the second number `(15 8)` passes the `elif` statement. Before that time, it is still 100. I debugged it before coming here.

Note:
I tried [this](http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-2e6f595683d5c0084a2c6b56c6b1f100?convert_to_webp=true) and [this](http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-acda5e2cea3a3e0d89e9365b0c46acf1?convert_to_webp=true) but no luck.

#### Update

This input:

```
2
4 15 7
8 8 6
```

produces the output:

```
92, -14
```

I expected:

```
92, 79
```

Comment: How do you actually create that object/call the function?

Comment: There are multiple serious issues with this code. You should break your original problem down into smaller chunks and ask for help with each one. A quick list of serious things to fix now: (1.) `input` in Python2 causes `eval` and should be avoided. (2.) Your class is worthless and does not define a real object. (3.) Your game logic should be literally anywhere besides an `__init__` method.

Comment: As it stands, this is a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (although presumably with a much better title)

Comment: I have poop=calculate_bid(player,first_moves,second_moves) (Yes, weird variable. That's why I excluded it)

Comment: @ Two-Bit Alchemist. Can you explain (1) and (2) and how it related with this 100=0?

Comment: @Realdeo Those have nothing to do with the error in your code. They are about its weird design/structure.

Comment: @Realdeo (1.) `input` in Python 2 means "take whatever anyone types in this box and executes it as real Python code on my computer". If you can't think of anything bad that could happen because of it, rest assured, clever people can and will exploit this. Use it with the appropriate amount of caution (read: almost never.) (2.) You tell me: what is a "calculate bid object"? Note that I mean in the context of the real world, not your program.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist This works likes secret-bid auction. Who bids most has his/her money deducted. (I only get into this point, the object given to the highest bidder is not yet coded)

Comment: @Realdeo That is an explanation of what your program does, but not a description of an object. An object is like a card, a bidder, a dealer, even a GameController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what your code is supposed to do, but presumably you want to subtract moves from cash. That's what you do inside the loop in the `if` and `elif` clause, and inside the `if` section of the `else` clause. But then, in the `else / else` section, you set the cash to the negative moves:

```
self.yourCash=-self.yourMove[self.x]
```

while you probably wanted to write

```
self.yourCash -= self.yourMove[self.x]
```

Comment: Thanks. However, my number doesn't enter the mentioned else.

Comment: @Realdeo: Yes it does.

Comment: @sth. No it doesn't. self.myMove[self.x] never equal self.yourMove[self.x]. 4 != 8 and 15 != 8 respectively.

Comment: @Realdeo: It does because the comparison in the `elif` doesn't work as intended (see my answer). If you put a print in the `else` case you'll see the that the current code really does enter that case.

Comment: @Realdeo Listen to what the people helping you are saying. Read sth's answer where it is clearly explained. You're **not** comparing `self.myMove[self.x] and self.yourMove[self.x]`, but `selfmyMove` in its entirety and `self.yourMove[self.x]`. So the else branch **isn't** just the case where they are equal, because your `if/elif/else` tree doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I got it. Thanks :p This is getting awkward. Sorry, guys. Just, in a rage mood, tbh. (Hence, the variable name)

Answer (score 2):

First, in this line you compare the move against the whole `self.myMove` array:

```
elif self.myMove<self.yourMove[self.x]:
```

Really you wanted to compare to the element at position `self.x`

```
elif self.myMove[self.x]<self.yourMove[self.x]:
```

This bug cases the `else` branch to be taken, where you run into the problem that Carsten already mentioned, where you negate the move instead of subtracting it. Instead of

```
self.yourCash=-self.yourMove[self.x]
```

You'd want

```
self.yourCash-=self.yourMove[self.x]
```

Comment: Thanks also. But it has nothing to do with the math

Comment: @Realdeo You are very narrowly focussed on the specific problem that your output doesn't match what you want. What you are failing to realize is that there are **systemic problems** with the way you approached this. Your code is so badly designed that there are dozens of flaws to point out, and you're refusing to listen to any you don't think directly correlate. **They all correlate.** You're trying to sail a ship full of holes.

Comment: @sth Your answer is the better one. I overlooked the first error (but, to be honest, this question is more of a guessing game anyway).